# Soft limit handling for maximum number of open files

Tags: macos, unix

I am writing an app for Mac OS 10.6.x/10.7.x. In my app, I want to detect the error that the softlimit for maximum number of opened file descriptors is reached (as reported by ulimit -n). I am sure there should be a signal for it, but I am not able to find it. There are documented signals related to softlimits for CPU and maximum file size, but not for file descriptors. Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get an error (via `errno`) when opening a file; you won't get a signal.

```
int fd = open("somefile", O_CREAT);
if (fd < 0)
{
    if (errno == EMFILE)
    {
        // Hit process file descriptor limit
    }
    else if (errno == ENFILE)
    {
        // Hit system file descriptor limit
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the error will occur when the hard limit is reached not on the soft limit. Crossing the soft limit should result in some sort of warning to the process.

Comment: @Aarkan That's not how it works - the difference with soft and hard limits is more about what can be changed; the code I have provided will happen when the soft limit is hit.

Answer (score 0):

`getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE);` seems to be what you are looking for.